# jQuery toggle div only works for first checkbox

Tags: jquery, css

So I have this script where multiple check boxes are located,
I have a script that shows additional buttons when you check a checkbox,
But the script is only working for the first checkbox on the page whilst all checkboxes have the same ID.

One of the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkstate" name="diritems[]" value=".snap" onclick="javascript:Toggle(this);">
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkstate').change(function(){
    if ($('#checkstate').is(':checked'))
        $('.addopt').fadeIn('Fast', 'linear');
    else
        $('.addopt').fadeOut('Fast', 'linear');

});});
```

So this will only work on the first checkbox with the first id="checkstate" found on the page, Any other checkbox won't do anything.

(P.S. the togglethis is a seperate function, which does work)

Comment: **Id** names has to be unique in a document: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: try using a different selector (maybe use a class if relevant), or if not, add an **attribute** and select on it, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id should be unique in the page. When you try to find multiple elements with the same id, you will only get the first element.

Use a class for the checkboxes instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkstate" name="diritems[]" value=".snap" onclick="javascript:Toggle(this);">
```

Now you can find all of them:

```
$('.checkstate').change(function(){
  ...
```

Comment: Offcourse it should be a class instead of ID, Been working on it too long by not noticing I guess!,

Thank you!

Comment: What if the checkbox is checked by another script? Like pressing a TD will check the checkbox but will not trigger the script.

Comment: @Sjef92: Changes by script won't trigger events, but you can use the jQuery `trigger` method to trigger the event from the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a class to target them (*or another selector can can apply to multiple elements*) and then use the `this` keyword to target the actual clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkstate').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('.addopt').fadeIn('Fast', 'linear');
        } else {
            $('.addopt').fadeOut('Fast', 'linear');
        }

    });
});
```